# Could not be resolved in the current scope or context

Tags: c#, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4

> *'fieldName' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make
>   sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas
>   are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.*

That message appears when I declare `_data` in my controller :

```
string orderBy = sidx + " " + sord;
IQueryable<Table> _data;
_data = entities.Table.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Any help?

Comment: You've tagged MVC 4.. is this code in a view or in your controller? or... where? Also.. you're attempting to OrderBy a string.. you need to make it an expression. In fact, all of your LINQ expressions appear to be variables.. are they expressions?

Comment: in MVC2 i try that way, and its work.
this is in my coltroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks For the Answer, now i realize it though... the problem is because the `sidx` parameter that i got from `fieldName` in header jqgrid does not recognize the table name. I then tried to do it this way and now it solved :)

Adding `it.` to order variable:

```
string orderBy = "it."+ sidx + " " + sord; IQueryable<Table> _data;
_data = entities.Table.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Comment: Yes, most commonly you've forgotten the `it.` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that the `orderBy` expression you have generated references the field which is not available in the `Table` - just set a breakpoint in this line and check what value it has.

One important thing here is that in case of jqGrid (you have tagged your question with jqGrid) there are some inconsistencies in what is being send as `sidx`. Most of the time it is the `index` from `colModel` but sometimes (for example when grouping is enabled) it can be `name`.

Comment: i set breakpoint there, and already check it. the sidx have value same like fieldName in my Table.

i tag jqgrid, because that sidx is parameter i got from jqgrid when i  short the header jqgrid.

Comment: @SilverCrow The error message comes clearly from Linq expressions so somethign must be going on there.

Comment: yes, the message appear because this :
.OrderBy(orderby)  ---> .OrderBy("FieldName asc")
if i use normal case like this:
.OrderBy(x=>x.Field)
its work.

why?

Comment: @SilverCrow It is hard to say exactly with such a little data. I would at least need to know which ORM you are using and what are you using for string based OrderBy (Dynamic LINQ or something else). It would be also  good to know some details about your model and the property which is causing the issue (maybe we have a nested property problem here or something like this). Without more details I can be only guessing.